# incorrect project reference GUIDs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, project-reference

I have projects in Visual Studio solution that have project references that include the wrong GUID for the referenced project. (don't know why, some of them may be recreated etc.)

The solution is loading a even build correctly, but I'm not sure what problem this could cause.

Any ideas if this is a problem? Why is GUID in project reference?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to fix this by hand. I had such an issue: wrong GUIDs made msbuild fail when building a solution file

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen once.

The builds would work on the developer machine.

But the CI builds would fail.

My occurred because a code-generator created the .csproj files and the reference was "missed".

The only thing I found was to drop the reference and re-add it through the VS IDE.
Pain in the butt, but it restored the builds on the CI machine.

So the question is.... did something besides VS create the .csproj?

And maybe...was the code ever updated from VS2003, etc.

Comment: thanks. But CI build are also worknig.(TFS 2013, git repository) And I'm not sure how was .csproj created.